# How to append new record of everyday to a new row in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe which contains an aggregated value till today. My datastream will update everyday so that I want to monitoring the change of each day. How can I append each newday's data to the dataframe?

The format will be like this,

```
   Date      Agg_Value
2022-12-07      0.43
2022-12-08      0.44
2022-12-09      0.41
 ...            ...
```

Comment: pd.concat? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat

Answer (score 0):

You want to use pandas.concat to bring together 2 dataframes:

```html
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.Series(['a', 'b'])
s2 = pd.Series(['c', 'd'])
print(pd.concat([s1, s2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you always have yesterday's dataframe available, you can simply  execute a script that runs everyday to get today's date and concatenate the result.

```py
# Assuming you have todays value
today_value = 42

# Get today's date
from datetime import date
today = date.today()

# Create a new dataframe with today's value
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Date':[str(today)],
        'Agg_value':[today_value]
    }
)

# Update df by concatenating today's data
df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways:
creating example dataframe -

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

```
Date = pd.date_range("2022-12-01", periods=4, freq="D")
Avg_value = np.random.rand(4)
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Date, Avg_value)), columns=['Date','Avg_value'])
df
```

will give -

[image]

1. `.loc`

Now add single row by -

`df.loc[len(df.index)] = [pd.Timestamp("2022-12-05"), 0.67]`

will give-

[image]

2. by `append`

```
new_row = {'Date': pd.Timestamp("2022-12-06"), 'Avg_value': 0.39}
df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
df
```

[image]

3. `concat` example is explained in [Arturo Sbr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74722862/4858908) answer